# Error with list index out of range only when merge sorting more than 512 numbers

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I'm working in Python with an implementation of merge sort that fails when more than 512 elements are in the list to be sorted.

The relevant code is below:

```
def mergeSort(oldList):
    if len(oldList) > 1:
        list1 = mergeSort(oldList[:len(oldList)/2])
        list2 = mergeSort(oldList[len(oldList)/2:])
        newList = merge(list1, list2)
        return newList
    else:
        return oldList

def merge(list1, list2):
    newList = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while(len(list1) > i or len(list2) > j):
        print i, j
        if len(list1) is i:
            newList.append(list2[j])
            j = j + 1
        elif len(list2) is j:
            newList.append(list1[i])
            i = i + 1
        elif list1[i] > list2[j]:
            newList.append(list2[j])
            j = j + 1
        else:
            newList.append(list1[i])
            i = i + 1
    return newList

unsortedList = [ randint(0,100) for i in range(513) ]
mergeSortedList = mergeSort(unsortedList)
```

When I change 513 in the next to last line to any smaller integer, the code works as expected. Starting at 513, I get the following error:

> File "./sortcomparison.py", line 129, in merge
>
> ```
> elif list1[i] > list2[j]:
> ```
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by changing `if len(list1) is i:` and `elif len(list2) is j:` to `if len(list1) == i:` and `elif len(list2) == j:`. Would someone be able to explain the difference between the two, and why it resulted in broken code with the original?

Comment: In Python `is` checks if both the variables point to the same object, whereas the `==` sign checks if the values for the two variables are the same.

Answer (score 0):

To see where the code is failing you can add a `try except` block around the `if else` block in merge function.

To resolve the error replace `is` with `==` in your `merge` function.

`is` is used to comparing whether two variables refer to same object and `==` is used for checking equality.

More on this [here](https://dbader.org/blog/difference-between-is-and-equals-in-python)